# Using two ng-clicks, not working

Tags: html, angularjs, accordion, ng-show

I am working on a collapsible table.

I have a table with a `ng-show.` The header panel of the table uses an `ng-click` that toggles the `ng-show` piece to be true or false. However, I want to have a button at the top that toggles all the tables to one way or the other. It works unless I click on an individual table. If an individual table is clicked the toggle button ignores that table. Here's an example of what the code looks like.

```
<h3>{{page.name}}
    <button type="button"ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">Toggle</button> 
</h3>

<div>
    <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">
        <h3>{{table.name}}</h3>
    </div>

    <table ng-show="!isOpen">
       ~~table contents~~
    </table>
</div>
```

The tables start out open, then close when either the toggle button is pressed or their headers are clicked. However the toggle button fails to change a table if it has been altered by clicking on the header.
One button would be the best, but having two buttons (one that opens them all, and one that closes them all) would work well too, and I feel might be the only way.

Comment: can you update with Error console  ? and some  controller coding ..

Comment: Your code is working as expected. Check the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sNKYi2MoRpjAT4sMA74P

Comment: @DhirenPatel I see it works there, but in my application it does not

Comment: Then you need to provide more details about application or create fresh plnkr which reproduces scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button"ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">Toggle</button>  
//lose a space.... and did you init the isOpen?
<button type="button" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">Toggle</button>
```